# access data from two table

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Customer class have name property that corresponds to name field in customer table.
Customer class also define the map that use for put the fieldName and fieldValue.

on database customer name define in customer table and fieldvalue define in form table.
now how i can retrieve customer name from customer table and fieldvalue from form table.
in hbm file:

```
<map name="formFields" table="form" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="true">
    <key column="id"/>
    <index column="fieldName" type="string"/>
    <element column="fieldValue" type="string"/>
 </map>
```

i want display two items.
i have one class, first item is property in same class and second item is define as a map value of a map key in map function in same class. both items are defined on separately tables. how display both the items

Answer (score 0):

You can use either SELECT JOIN SQL query when reading the data, and ON UPDATE CASCADE SQL queries when creating/updating data.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it like this. Just

- create a entity class `Form`
- define a `one-to-one` relationship in your `hbm.xml`, between `Customer` and `Form`
- create a property `Form form` in your `Customer` class
- define a method in your DAO or whatever to return you `name` and `value` as a map.

Comment: in which class to define method that return name and value as a map..in Form class or Customer class?

Comment: @singh: Neither. Define it in some, CustomerDAO class, or say it CustomerDaoHelper, or name it CustomerDataUtil or whatever suits you.